# Problem with the engine Volvo S40

Tags: volvo, s40

I have a problem, the error code is 2008

The throttle valve is still dead, even after I replaced the throttle and gas pedal. The indicator lights up. There is often a lack of power as it would suffocate. What should I do? What could be the reason for this?

Thank you.

-Volvo S40 with Electronic Throttle Motor (ETM)

Comment: Questions in English please.

Answer (score 1):

The suffocating is indicative of lack of fuel, air or combustion. Have you checked the spark plugs? If they look "blackened", they are worn out. If they are wet with fuel, the spark plug wires or ignition coils might be faulty, thus not sparking the plug. 
Also check if the air filter is full of dust, that will restrict air flow.
I have had a similar issue on an old BMW, which turned out to be incorrect timing. That is extremely unlikely, but worth looking at if you have recently had the timing belt changed.
The fuel injectors could be clogged or faulty too. They are expensive to replace, you should go through the "easy" things before looking at them.